# Перенаправление

Tags: блокировки, провайдер

Проблема следующая.
Мой оператор FreshTel при финансовой блокировке блокирует интернет, и происходит это не где-то там на сервере, а на моем компьютере. Т.е. драйвер модема что то где то прописывает на моем компьютере, и любой клик в браузере перенаправляется на сайт интернет оператора.
Все бы хорошо, но когда я подключаюсь к интернету через другого оператора (МТС), то перенаправление все равно остается, и я вижу все тот же сайт. Что делать?
Файл HOSTS программой не затрагивается. Может где то в другом месте прописывает?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте такие способы:

1) сделайте жесткий рефреш страницы - ctrl+R или ctrl+shift+R
2) обновите записи dns клиента ( перезапустить службу в windows )
3) проверьте через какой dns сервер проходят ваши запросы ( в консоли nslookup yandex.ru )
4) сделайте трассировку до сайта, возможно включен прокси ( tracert/traceroute yandex.ru )

Comment: Спасибо, прям первое же и помогло. Но с чем это связанно?

Comment: с вашим браузером, он кеширует страницы